# Can't debug android application

Tags: android

I'm developing android application in android platform 2.2,. I am not able to debug applications. I'm facing a problem wherein there are no errors in the program, but whenever I run the application on emulator, it gets launched but stops unexpectedly and I'm forced to close the application.

Comment: Did u try to actually debug it??

Comment: 1. Try analyzing the logcat output. It can give you some cue. 2. Have a look at the dmesg output as well, that can also highlight the issues.

Comment: Try using the Log command to print stuff to logcat. Then see where exactly it stops. Then maybe post the code here. That might get more help.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies...m tryn things ...

Answer (score 0):

hey Supriya!!!!!!!!!!!!!
this means your application is crashing somewhere. see log  for crash or exception details.

and for debug add following attribute in android  manifest file under application tag
android:debuggable="true"

Thanks.